# Clickable Fetched Data: Domain Issue

Tags: php, html

I just can't find the right query for this kind of problem. I am working with some old data in the database. Fetching a column where website links are saved and displaying them are fine. I just noticed that some links are not using the domain `.com` and some use just `htt:/`. Those data with `htt:/` are fine but I can't get it to work with the data with no `.com`.

How to make the links work having domains other than `.com`?

---

**Sample:**

`$row['website']` is `www.website.net`

**Code:**

```
<?php
..
..

echo "<a href='http://" . trim($row['website'],'http://') . "/' target='_blank' title='Visit Website'>" . $row['cname'] . "</a>";
?>
```

**The Output:**

Some became `www.website.ne` and `www.website.` resulting to kind of broken links.

**Desired Output:**

`www.website.net`

Comment: have you found the answer?

Comment: @Talhiner Not yet. I'm going to try to solve this now and hoping to find a simple solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the unrestricted format of links saved in the database, I renewed the code. Just removed the `trim()` and added a 3-lines of conditional code. I just checked if the link has a like-of `htt` characters then it will display the link as is, else a `http://` will be added. Links with different domains or TLD are working now with that logic.

Thanks to `stripos()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

```
$websitename="www.website.ne";  //your $row['website']

$extention_ary=explode(".",$websitename);
$extention=array_pop($extention_ary);
$new_extention="";
if($extention=="" || $extention=="ne"){
$new_extention=".net";
}

$new_website_name=implode(".",$extention_ary).$new_extention;
echo    $new_website_name;
```

Comment: That will make the code long for there are different domains like `.ph`, `.edu`, `.gov`, etc.